Displaying the picture taken from user in flutter
I am a trainee in flutter, and I created a button which takes the image as input from user using image_picker, and now I want to display that image in my second screen. So how can I do that with arrayList?
I taken the image as input in the form only, it is not saved anywhere it is just on the page.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can display the captured image by passing the image's path to the second page on navigating.
Navigator.of(context).push(
      PageRouteBuilder(
        pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => SecondPage("<path_to_image>")
      ),
    );

In SecondPage
Image.file(
   File("<path_to_image>"),
)

